# Stripe how to do a transfer with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am currently using Stripe (test mode), but I can't make a transfer.
I can make payments without any problems, but I always have a problem when I have to send part of the payment to another account.

[image: Dashboard Stripe Error]

I follow this : https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react#setup

In my server.js :

```
app.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let {status} = await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 200000,
            currency: "usd",
            source: "tok_visa",
            transfer_group: "tr_test",
            source: req.body
        });
        res.json({status});
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
})
app.post("/transfer", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let {status} = await stripe.transfers.create({
            amount: 100000,
            currency: "usd",
            destination: "acct_1DUAayISchW15mGi",
            transfer_group: "tr_test"
        });
        res.json({status});
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
})
```

And on my checkoutForm.js :

```
async submit(ev) {
    let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
    let response = await fetch("/charge", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
      body: token.id
    });
    if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")
    let response2 = await fetch("/transfer", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
      body: token.id
    });
    if (response2.ok) console.log("Transfers Complete!")
  }
```

The Charge is ok, not the transfer ...

If someone can help me or give me a tutorial, I would be more than happy !

Comment: Are transfers available in their sandbox environment?

Comment: The error message returned tells you that the issue is with the destination account id. You're trying to transfer funds to acct_1DUAayISchW15mGi which can not work since it's your own Stripe account. You can only transfer funds to a connected account, not your own. So create a Custom account https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts and then transfer funds to that account

Comment: @Dadsquatch How can I check if it is available?

Comment: @koopajah in my case I want to send to an existing account, how can I do it?

Comment: The "custom account" is an easy way to test out transfers for your testing; in practice, if you want to transfer to an existing online business that already has a Stripe account that's a "standard account" -- you need to connect their account to your platform, following the steps in https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts.

Comment: @ElliotNelson Yes, but I don't understand, I have the impression that the "customer" must validate the connection of the "partner" account.

Comment: Well, there are multiple parties here: "platform" (that's you, building this application, with a Stripe account); the business you call "partner" (Stripe calls this a "standard account"); and the eventual "customer" (they will enter their credit card into a form to purchase something, which will pay YOU, the platform, and you'll transfer some of those funds to the partner).  The customer will never know anything about Stripe, they just enter their CC#.  But you need to build OAuth functionality for the _partner_ to authorize the connection between the platform (you) and their Stripe account.

Comment: Stripe refers to this as an "onboarding flow" -- it's the web pages you need to build that allow a business out there to sign up for your platform, enter their business details, select their settings and template and such (if applicable, however your platform works), and then link their existing Stripe standard account with your platform's Stripe account so that you are authorized to transfer them funds.  (You cannot just "transfer" funds to any random Stripe account without authorization.)

Comment: @ElliotNelson We agree, so I have to make a page with this -> https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#integrating-oauth that allows the partner to validate his account, and another page where my customer will proceed to the payment, right?

Comment: @Verdouze Exactly so, two different parts of your application.

Comment: @ElliotNelson And I store the id that the oauth returns to me, and that's the one I would use for payments, right?

Comment: Right (or just to be extra clear, you'll process payments from customer using your own account, and you'll use the id that oauth returns to you to process transfers to your partners).